# What happens when you teach the same plan twice to the blacksmith (or the jeweller)?

Tags: diablo-iii

Should I be checking every time I'm about to give a new plan to the blacksmith (or the jeweller), that he doesn't know it yet ?  Currently I'm not, and hoping that, in this particular case, the game will give me an error like "The blacksmith already knows this plan" and will spare the item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what happens indeed. You already see it when you hover over the plans. It says: Already known.

[image: Already known black smith recipes]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xw02n.jpg shows this

Comment: Thanks for that picture, if you dont mind I'll add it to the answer. If not I'll remove it again of course.